# What does the "integrity" attribute of equipment mean?

Tags: elite-dangerous

When selecting equipment for my ship, I note that items have a value listed for "integrity", usually either A or B.

See, for example, that this mining laser has an integrity value of A:

[image]

What does this value mean? What effect does it have in the game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As cmdr Freiheit posited in comments, the integrity rating is an indication of how much damage a component can take before failing.

This was stated by Frontier Developments staff on the game's forum here: 
https://forums.frontier.co.uk/showthread.php?t=102717&p=1591966&viewfull=1#post1591966

> "Also the [specific variant of module] has a higher integrity rating so
>   that it can take more punishment before failing."